# Runtime Controller in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Can you help me to explain relationship between time in Runtime Controller and Ramp_up period value of Thread group?
I tested

Number of Thread: 1

Ramp_Up Period: 1

Loop count: 1

Runtime Controller: 5s

->Elapsed time of current running test: 5s

But with case

Number of Thread: 5

Ramp_Up Period: 5

Loop count: 1

Runtime Controller: 5s

->Elapsed time of current running test: 10s

I don't understand why it become 10s.

Could you help me to explain more?

Answer (score 1):

Ramp up is the time to execute all threads, runtime is controlling each thread execution.

In your case, ramp up 5 seconds means last thread will be executed after 5 seconds. Last thread will enter runtime controller which will run 5 seconds of execution. Thus 10 seconds is the maximum of your execution.

Comment: hmm. thank for explaination. Can you explain more in the case Number of Thread: 5

Ramp_Up Period: 5

Loop count: 2

Runtime Controller: 5s

Comment: Last thread start after 5 seconds. Loop twice 5 seconds each. Should be ~15 seconds

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't understand about runtime. Could you explian more? Why last thread will enter runtime controller? How about first thread?

Comment: Doing 5 threads with ramp up 5 will create new thread every second

Answer (score 0):

Runtime Controller acts according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so it defines how long its **children** are allowed to run.

Normally you should be using it in conjunction with Loop Count = `Forever` or `-1` on either [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) level.

So

- if you want the whole test to run for 5 seconds - use "Scheduler" section of the Thread Group
- if you want only certain sampler(s) to run for 5 seconds - put them under the Runtime Controller, however the whole test duration will depend on when the last sampler enters the Runtime Controller

Also be aware that JMeter "asks" threads to stop so it might take some extra time to let them gracefully shut down.